# Certificate chaining error in Websphere

Tags: ssl-certificate, websphere-7

I am trying to consume a RESTful service from url https://someurl.com.
I have added the following properties in my code:

```
 Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
 Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");
 Security.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");
 Security.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keystore.jks");
 Security.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
 Security.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
```

The configuration changes that I have done so far are:

1. set `com.ibm.websphere.ssl.retrieveLeafCert` to `true`
2. retrieved the certificate using url as someurl and port 443 and added it to the truststore.
3. restarted the server

But I am getting the following exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed:          java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:
  java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Walmart Root CA, O=Wal-Mart Stores Inc is not trusted; internal cause is:
  java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
  at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:22)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:423)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:192)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:176)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:53)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:464)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:545)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:530)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:79)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:142)
  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:686)
  at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:98)
  at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:13)
  at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.connect(b.java:6)
  at com.dwl.tcrm.tester.RESTClient_2.main(RESTClient_2.java:76)
```

Answer (score 22):

I'm assuming you have a web application, which is trying to access that restful service.

First, you should not set your stores via `javax.net.ssl.*` properties, but use SSL configurations provided in WebSphere. So comment all these `setProperty()` calls. 
Second, you have to add your service server certificate to the trust store.

Login to web admin console:

- Go to `Security > SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultTrustStore > Signer certificates`
- Click `Retrieve from port` button, and specify hostname, 443 port, and Alias.
- Click `Retrieve singer information` button.
- Verify, if correct certificate is imported (parent).
- Save, and restart.

In some versions, the child certificate was imported (not the root), in that case, you will have to manually download the root certificate and intermediate (e.g. via browser, and import that one to the `NodeDefaultTrustStore`, but this time using `Add` button, not `Retrieve..`

Comment: as I mentioned in my post, I have already added the certificate to the trust store.But it made no difference.Also, I tried to hit the service through a standalone Rest Client and it is giving the same error.

Comment: @AyanBiswas But you are adding it to the `(javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks)` probably not to the `NodeDefaultTrustStore` Did you remove these `setProperty` calls? As they are pointing to the different stores than these used by WebSphere. And you shouldn't set the `com.ibm.websphere.ssl.retrieveLeafCert` property to `true`, as the whole idea of chained certs is to use root cert instead of leaf.

Comment: I think this answer should be acceped, it did solve the issue for me.

Comment: Hi all, we faced the similar issue, installed the certificate and it got resolved. But we don't understand how did the problem come up in first place. We have been running our application from past 3-4 years and are seeing this issue for the very first time now. Any information is appreciated.

Comment: I can only speculate that after 4 years someone changed the cert on the target service you are trying to call (eg. expired) and you needed to import new one.

Answer (score 3):

This means your certificate is not added in cacerts. Try to execute this command as

keytool -list -v -keystore your_path_to_cacerts (Provide the list of cert in cacerts)
check by matching the serial number of your certificate. If it is not there then please follow the steps given below

To export the Intermediate certificate: Internet Explorer -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates ->
To view the Certificate Path: Select Certificate -> View -> Certification Path ->
To Export the Certificate: Select Certificate -> Export -> DER

encoded Binary Format -> Save ( From Firefox -> Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Encryption -> View Certificates )
(Given here - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21592616) after this add this exported certificate with below command

keytool -import -trustcacerts -Keystore CACERTS(path) -alias alias -file cert path export in step 3

My issue was the same and I am able to resolve it by following these steps