# Certificate chaining error : PKIX path validation failed

Tags: ssl, smtp, websphere, ssl-certificate, jakarta-mail

I am frequently getting below exceptions. Please advise what to do..

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Fail to verify issuer; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1564)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1551)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:935)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:426)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include some code and/or explanation of what you're trying to do when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Very generic error, Possibly some certificates are missing(java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error) in the trust store.

Please include more info about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your smtp server is using chained certificates and you imported only last one in chain. You will have to add as signers to the trust store all certificates in the path. Check this post [Certificate chaining error in Websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705559/3701228), it provides some additional info how to add certs to truststore.