# Install .pfx file in WAS 6 and call https webservice

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, certificate, websphere

I know very little about SSL, pfx file etc.

I am supposed to call a https Rest webservice (which will an internal service to the organisation) from my application (running on WAS 6 on  linux server which is managed by a seperate team) which is one of the enhancement I am working on. I used to be using the below piece.

```
    public class SSLInfo {
    public void sslContextInitialization() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        try {
            ctx.init(new KeyManager[0],
                    new TrustManager[] { new DefaultTrustManager() },
                    new SecureRandom());
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//      SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
    }
}


class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    public DefaultTrustManager() {
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public 509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I used to call sslContextInitialization() before calling the webservice which worked fine but I understand is not secure.

I am now asked to remove all these lines of code before the service call and am given a **.PFX file along with a username and password**. I was informed that the certificates should be installed on the WAS server (which the server management team informed is done) and then my application would work fine without any SSL related code. I doubt if this is the right way to be doing.

Now that my app is deployed to the server without the ssl context initialization code, I can see the below error in application logs now-

**java.net.SocketException: Default SSL context init failed: null**

Please help me understand this and let me know what needs to be done from my application to be able to hit the service successfully.

OR can this be fully handled from my application itself without adding anything in the server? If yes please guide.

Comment: In general you shouldn't embed SSL logic in application for simple https call. See some comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27705559/3701228). The .pfx file usually contains private key, which is used do authentication over SSL. Is this what you are looking for? Do you have to authenticate using SSL cert? You should configure [Dynamic outbound endpoint SSL](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/usec_sslnewdynendconf.html?lang=en) via console, instead embedding it in app.